# Data insert in loop using sql bulkcopy class c#

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

i have two database now i have to insert data from one db to another db in loop. i know bit sql bulk copy and i do not know how to insert one data at a time using sql bulk copy.

here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [CandidateApplication](
 [EmailID] [varchar](300) NOT NULL,
 [Name] [varchar](300) NULL,
 [FileName] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [IsDownloaded] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

basically i need to fetch data from one db with clause like `IsDownloaded=0` and then i need to iterate in loop. with in loop i will get file path from `FileName` field and download that file. if the file download successfully then i have to save that data from db1 to db2 and update field `IsDownloaded=1` to db1.

can i handle the data insert from one db to another db with in loop using sqlbulk copy class. please suggest. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you wouldn't need to iterate over the data inserting one by one, all you need to do is to pass a collection into the WriteToServer() method.

an example is:

```
HashSet<SomeObject> dataLines = new HashSet<SomeObject>(); 

foreach (var entity in someCollection)
        {
            if(entity == somecondition)
            {
                  dataLines.Add(new SomeObject
                              {
                                  CollectionItem1 = entity.Property1,
                                  CollectionItem2 = entity.Property2,
                                  CollectionItem3 = entity.Property3,
                                  CollectionItem4 = entity.Property4,
                                  CollectionItem5 = entity.Property5,
                                  CollectionItem6 = entity.Property6,
                                  CollectionItem7 = entity.Property7,
                              });
            }
        }
        try
        {
            _context.Connection.Open();
            EntityConnection connection = _context.Connection as EntityConnection;
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
            if (connection != null)
            {
                sqlConnection = connection.StoreConnection as SqlConnection;
            }

            if (sqlConnection != null)
            {

                SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection);
                bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable";
                bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add("CollectionItem1", "Column1");
                bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add("CollectionItem2", "Column2");
                bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add("CollectionItem3", "Column3");
                bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add("CollectionItem4", "Column4");
                bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add("CollectionItem5", "Column5");
                bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add("CollectionItem6", "Column6");
                bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add("CollectionItem7", "Column7");
// dataLines is a collection of objects
                bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dataLines.AsDataReader());
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _context.Connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: can u plzz give me bit full code. give me code for dataLines. thanks

Comment: datalines in this case is simply a Hashset<T>

Comment: how do u assign data to dataLines before inserting into db?

Comment: I've modified the above for you

Comment: can't we use List instead of HashSet ? if not please tell me the reason.

Comment: Of course you can use a list, i used a hashset as i overrode the equality members so i could ensure that each item within that collection was unique based on a variety of factors that were applied when adding an item to the collection, rather than doing a distinct later on

Answer (score 1):

It is simple dude:) Sorry my code in VB.net I hope you dont mind it

**Note: The important thing is datatype in your datatable and destination table. They should be same**

1. Fetch data from db1 and do whatever you want to do and get ready the data in datatable
2. Use this function to dump your data in 2nd database

Code:

```
  Public Shared Function BulkSave(ByVal dt As DataTable) As Boolean
    Dim mydb As New CSdatabase
    Try

    Dim connectionString = "Connection String"
    '' so there is no need to map columns. 
        Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(connectionString)
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 25000
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 300

            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("EmailID", "EmailID")
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name")
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("FileName", "FileName")
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("IsDownloaded", "IsDownloaded")
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.CandidateApplication"

            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        'mydb.closeConnection() ' Close your conneciton here
    End Try

    Return True

End Function
```

Comment: the batchsize is 25000 rows in 300 seconds

Comment: i know how to use SqlBulkCopy class. my question was different that when i would use SqlBulkCopy  then can i update data in loop means one at a time?

Comment: If you want to update one row at a time then you don't need sqlbulkCopy. SqlBulkCopy is slower in that case.

Comment: i need to know is it at all feasible to update data with SqlBulkCopy in loop one-by-one...if yes then can u guide me with code sample. thanks

Comment: no It is not feasible to update with loop, Bulk update means you have a lot of data and you want to update in DB and in this statement. I don't understand why you need loop?